# If in jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote this script, but it doesn't work in way I wanted:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#map_container').find('#point').length == 0 ) {
        $("#map_container").click(function (e) { 
            var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
            var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
            //alert('left: '+relativeXPosition+', top: '+relativeYPosition);
            $("#map_container").append('<img id="point" src="<?=url::base();?>images/city.png" alt="" />');
            $("#point").css({ top: (relativeYPosition) + 'px', left: relativeXPosition + 'px', position: 'absolute' })
        }); 
    }
});
```

It should put only one img with id="point", but when I click map_container two times I get two img's, why this if does not work?

Comment: The title could be edited to understand a bit better what the question is about... something like "Execute click event only once in jQuery"

Answer (score 5):

You say: "If the length is zero then every time the element is clicked, do a thing"

You mean: "Every time the element is clicked, if the length is zero, do a thing"

Put the test inside the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#map_container").click(function (e) { 
        if ($('#map_container').find('#point').length == 0 ) {
            var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
            var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
            //alert('left: '+relativeXPosition+', top: '+relativeYPosition);
            $("#map_container").append('<img id="point" src="<?=url::base();?>images/city.png" alt="" />');
            $("#point").css({ top: (relativeYPosition) + 'px', left: relativeXPosition + 'px', position: 'absolute' })
        } 
    });
});
```

You must make the if inside the click function.

Answer (score 2):

You only bind the `click()` if there's not already an image, *but* within the `click()` (which can be invoked several times) you're *not* performing this check. Therefore,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#map_container").click(function (e) { 
        if ($(this).find('#point').length == 0 ) {
            var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
            var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
            //alert('left: '+relativeXPosition+', top: '+relativeYPosition);
            $("#map_container").append('<img id="point" src="<?=url::base();?>images/city.png" alt="" />');
            $("#point").css({ top: (relativeYPosition) + 'px', left: relativeXPosition + 'px', position: 'absolute' })
        }
    }); 
});
```

To elaborate: In your code the `click()` handler is *bound* once (depending on the condition - which I suspect to always return true) but can be *invoked* several times always producing the same output. In the above, however, the `click()` handler performs the check on *every* invocation, thus only producing output when the condition is false (i.e., there is no `#point` yet).

**EDIT: `unbind()` / `one()`**
@tsimbalar has a pretty neat [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958284/if-in-jquery-does-not-work/3958321#3958321) using `unbind()`. That's clever *if* your `click()` does *not* contain an `else` part (to be executed if `#point` *does* exist). The same can be achieved by means of [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/): `$(...).one('click', function() { ... });`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#map_container").one('click', function (e) { 
        var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
        var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        //alert('left: '+relativeXPosition+', top: '+relativeYPosition);
        $("#map_container").append('<img id="point" src="<?=url::base();?>images/city.png" alt="" />');
        $("#point").css({ top: (relativeYPosition) + 'px', left: relativeXPosition + 'px', position: 'absolute' })
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I didn't know about the `one()` ... really nice !

Answer (score 2):

I understand that what you want is that the code for the `click` event should be executed only once.

Something like this would be better, I think :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#map_container").click(function (e) { 
            var relativeXPosition = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft);
            var relativeYPosition = (e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
            //alert('left: '+relativeXPosition+', top: '+relativeYPosition);
            $("#map_container").append('<img id="point" src="<?=url::base();?>images/city.png" alt="" />');
            $("#point").css({ top: (relativeYPosition) + 'px', left: relativeXPosition + 'px', position: 'absolute' })
            //we are done here, do not react to clicks anymore !
            $(this).unbind('click')
        });
});
```

note the `unbind`, saying you do not want to be called when a click occurs.